# tf_static and nodelet_manager unconnected for my Kinects

Tags: ros, openni, ros-hydro, tf-static, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently learned about the `roswtf` tool and have been trying to use it to determine where some things are going wrong.  When I use `roswtf` after launching my Kinects in separate terminals like so:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=kinect_1 device_id:=1@0 
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=kinect_2 device_id:=2@0 
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=kinect_3 device_id:=3@0
```

I receive this error:

```
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /kinect_2/kinect_2_nodelet_manager:
   * /tf_static
 * /kinect_1/kinect_1_nodelet_manager:
   * /tf_static
 * /kinect_3/kinect_3_nodelet_manager:
   * /tf_static
```

Is this anything to be concerned about? I can access all of my camera streams still- rbg, disparity, and depth.  What exactly does this error mean?  I've tried googling and looking on here and haven't seen this error. I'm using model #1473 Kinects and Hydro.

And to add to my confusion, this is the rqt_graph: [http://imgur.com/uFdxehH](https://imgur.com/uFdxehH) (I can't insert the picture it's too big)

It looks like they're connected to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115591/tf_static-and-nodelet_manager-unconnected-for-my-kinects/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-02**:
hi

me too, i have problem with tf_static and When I use roswtf, i find this warnings:
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:

- /camera/camera_nodelet_manager:

  - /tf_static
- /octomap_server:

  - /tf_static
    /rgbdslam:
  - /tf_static

**Comment by [sophye_turtlebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21913/sophye_turtlebot/) on 2015-04-02**:
did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is old, but I just had to find that out too.

Most probably, you are using a [TransformListener](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1TransformListener.html#details). The reason `tf_static` is reported as unconnected is that it automatically subscribes to both `tf` and `tf_static` (see [source](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1TransformListener.html#a95efa667c6c28633a814b2372b960302)). Now if you only use `tf` in your system (which is perfectly legal afaik), `tf_static` will not be connected.

---

Originally posted by [cellard0or](https://answers.ros.org/users/27123/cellard0or/) with karma: 61 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-05-31**:
+1. Btw, I found this warning confusing, so [filed a ticket](https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/165).